# Encountering a problem in my code to do multi level sorting

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to do this multi level sorting by copying the code from this link. I have only pasted the relevant code here

https://trumpexcel.com/sort-data-vba/

```
Public DestinationShVar as Worksheet
Public wDestination as workbook
  For Each sht In wDestination.Worksheets
  If sht.Name Like "*-*" Then Set DestinationShVar = sht
Next sht

With DestinationShVar.Sort
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AK1"), Order:=xlDescending
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Range("A:GB")
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With
```

I am getting an error of

> Object variable not set on

```
With DestinationShVar.Sort
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: Where do you set `wDestination`?

Comment: Due to privacy reasons, i didn't show it. Without sorting, the macro was working fine so i am assuming that's not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Public Issue

- The error might have occurred because you didn't declare the sht
  variable.
- You have to include the filter in the loop, otherwise it will loop
  through the worksheets and apply the filter only to the last found
  worksheet.
- You cannot declare a variable as **Public** inside of a procedure,
  you have to use **Dim** (or Static).

### The Code

```
Sub PublicIssue1()


    Dim WDestination As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set WDestination = Worksbooks("Boo1.xls")

    For Each sht In WDestination.Worksheets

        If sht.Name Like "*-*" Then

            With sht.Sort
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AK1"), Order:=xlDescending
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
                .SetRange Range("A:GB")
                .Header = xlYes
                .Apply
            End With

        End If

    Next sht

End Sub
```

If you are declaring a variable as **Public**, it has to be before all procedures in a module.

```
Public WDestination as Workbook

Sub PublicIssue2()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    'Set WDestination = Worksbooks("Boo1.xls") ' If it is not set.

    For Each sht In WDestination.Worksheets

        If sht.Name Like "*-*" Then

            With sht.Sort
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AK1"), Order:=xlDescending
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
                .SetRange Range("A:GB")
                .Header = xlYes
                .Apply
            End With

        End If

    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: The code i pasted was for illustrative purposes so public variable was set at the right place so i am assuming the issue was "You have to include the filter in the loop, otherwise it will loop through the worksheets and apply the filter only to the last found worksheet."